# make falling block not drop item if unable to be placed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make falling block not drop item if unable to be placed. If I remember correctly there is a tag for it. I might be wrong if so tell me thx Basically some falling blocks that when summoned will not become items when not able to be placed.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Dynamic_tiles

Comment: what do you mean with this? You mean it doesn't exist or that I should go to the link to find it

Comment: Go there and find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DropItem:0
```

Okay I found i... extra letters